# Check if an element exists when parsing XML

Tags: c#, xml

I'm parsing XML. I normally parse it the way I show in the code below which is straightforward The problem is that I don't own the XML I'm parsing and I can't change it. Sometimes there is no thumbnail element (there are no tags) and I get an `Exception`.

Is there a way to maintain this simplicity and check if the element exists? Or do I have to get first an `XElement` list with LINQ, to then check it and fill only the existing object properties?

```
void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    XDocument dataDoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(e.Result));

    var listitems = from noticia in dataDoc.Descendants("Noticia")
                    select new News()
                    {
                        id = noticia.Element("IdNoticia").Value,
                        published = noticia.Element("Data").Value,
                        title = noticia.Element("Titol").Value,
                        subtitle = noticia.Element("Subtitol").Value,
                        thumbnail = noticia.Element("Thumbnail").Value
                    };

    itemList.ItemsSource = listitems;
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**[Edit]**[Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5336758/588868) should be the accepted answer. It is far more readable and easier to apply.**[/edit]**

Create an extension method like this :

```
public static string TryGetElementValue(this XElement parentEl, string elementName, string defaultValue = null) 
{
    var foundEl = parentEl.Element(elementName);

    if (foundEl != null)
    {
        return foundEl.Value;
    }

    return defaultValue;
}
```

then, change your code like this :

```
select new News()
{
    id = noticia.TryGetElementValue("IdNoticia"),
    published = noticia.TryGetElementValue("Data"),
    title = noticia.TryGetElementValue("Titol"),
    subtitle = noticia.TryGetElementValue("Subtitol"),
    thumbnail = noticia.TryGetElementValue("Thumbnail", "http://server/images/empty.png")
};
```

This approach allows you to keep a clean code with isolating the check of element presence. It also allow you to define a default value, which can be helpful

Comment: better use:  return foundEl = (parentEl.Element(elementName) ? parentEl.Element(elementName).Value : defaultValue
or
 return (foundEl != null) ? foundEl.Value : defaultValue

Comment: Better: use the explicit conversion already present in XElement and the null coalescing operator for defaults...

Comment: Hi, after searching what an extension method and a null-coalescing operator are, I've implemented the same that is in the example you've given me, but inside the extension method I have:
return (parentEl.Element(elementName).Value ?? defaultValue);

Is this correct? I keep getting the NullReferenceException, now in that line.

Thank you

Comment: you reproduces the same error : if `parentEl.Element(elementName)` is null, you can't retrieve the Value property. Look at the sample. The .Value is called only if the elements exists

Comment: Ah ok, I see, sorry I'm not very concentrated it seems! I'll have a break :) thank you!

Comment: Just another question, what is the difference between creating an extension method and creating a normal method, in this case passing the XElement as another argument?

Comment: it's a matter of syntax. An extension method allow you to add a method to an existing object where an utility method require to pass the object as parameter: `myObject.MyExtensionMethod()` instead of `MyUtilityMethod(myobject)`.

Comment: I suppose both options would be correct but the extension method is cleaner isn't it?

Comment: @enkara: it depends on your habits... there is no universal rules. It's like asking what is the best between Debian and Suse... there are fanatics for the both, but none of them are 100% rights

Comment: Ok, thank you for all your help. I wanted to know this last thing to know the best practices in c#. As you have seen I'm just starting. Thank you

Answer (score 39):

Instead of using the `Value` property, if you cast to string you'll just get a null reference instead:

```
void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender,
                                DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    XDocument dataDoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(e.Result));

    var listitems = from noticia in dataDoc.Descendants("Noticia")
                    select new News()
                    {
                        id = (string) noticia.Element("IdNoticia"),
                        published = (string) noticia.Element("Data"),
                        title = (string) noticia.Element("Titol"),
                        subtitle = (string) noticia.Element("Subtitol"),
                        thumbnail = (string) noticia.Element("Thumbnail")
                    };

    itemList.ItemsSource = listitems;
}
```

That uses the explicit conversion from `XElement` to `string`, which handles a null input by returning a null output. The same is true for all explicit conversions on `XAttribute` and `XElement` to nullable types, including nullable value types such as `int?` - you just need to be careful if you're using *nested* elements. For example:

```
string text = (string) foo.Element("outer").Element("inner");
```

will give a null reference if `inner` is missing, but will still throw an exception if `outer` is missing.

If you want a "default" value, you can use the null coalescing operator (`??`):

```
string text = (string) foo.Element("Text") ?? "Default value";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` to deserialize it from xml to an object. Then if the element doesn't exist the property of the object will just get it's default value.

Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx
or the new path
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer

Answer (score 0):

You may use the code below:

`string content = item.Element("Content") == null ? "" : item.Element("Content").Value;`