# Substituting non-existing XML attribute with default value

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to make an XML parser for XML documents, where there are some optional attributes in nodes and I am looking for an elegant way, how to solve the problem with "Object reference not set to an instance".
I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336669/check-if-an-element-exists-when-parsing-xml-c-sharp) topic, which is very similar and the following code seemed very promising:

```
string text = (string) foo.Element("Text") ?? "Default value";
```

However, when I tried to implement it, the "Object reference not set to an instance" still occurred and so I am looking for another solution. Here is a piece of my desperate effort.

XML file 1:

```
...
<Message id ="1" appendix = "abc" ></Message>
...
```

XML file 2:

```
...
<Message id ="2" ></Message>
...
```

My parser (called in a cycle for each file in the folder):

```
public MyNode Parse(string file)
{
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.Load(file);

    MyNode node = new MyNode();
    node.messageID = (string)xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Message")[0].Attributes["id"].Value ?? "NULL";
    node.appendix = (string)xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Message")[0].Attributes["appendix"].Value ?? "NULL";

    return node;
}
```

Could you help me out?

Comment: What does the debugger say is null?

Comment: the ["appendix"] Attribute... I get the Null Reference Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Or maybe the Value of the Attribute, I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this only works if the `Value` is `null`, not if the actual `XAttribute` is `null`.

You'll have to do something like this:

```
XAttribute temp = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Message")[0].Attributes["appendix"];
if (temp == null)
{
    node.appendix = temp.Value;
} 
else
{
    node.appendix = "NULL";
}
```

Comment: Well, that is a sad discovery... anyway, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: can look a bit nicer with `node.appendix = temp == null ? "NULL" : temp.value;`

Answer (score 2):

Following LINQ to XML query will return `MyNode` object filled with values of message id and appendix attributes. If some attribute not found, then defalult value "NULL" is used:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(file);
var node = xDoc.Descendants("Message")
               .Select(m => new MyNode {
                   messageID = (string)m.Attribute("id") ?? "NULL",
                   appendix = (string)m.Attribute("appendix") ?? "NULL"
               }).FirstOrDefault();
```

If there is no `Message` elements in your xml document, then `null` will be returned.

BTW when you are using LINQ to XML its better to use casting node to `(string)` than accessing its `Value` property. Because if node not found in document, then you'll get `NullReferenceException` if you will try to get `Value` property of `null`. But when you cast node to `string`, you simply get `null` value instead of exception. That allows you to provide default value with null-coalescing operator.

Comment: Thank you very much for your exhaustive answer. Now, I have a bit better understanding of the parsing process. However, your colleague's answer was easier to implement in my code (I had to re-code less lines), so I accepted his answer.