# Check if an elements exist while parsing xml "Error No Sequence element"

Tags: c#, xml

i have an xml with different set tags, i want to check if an element exist since i am having error **no sequence element**  How do i check if tag szSerialNmbr is present, if not assign a null value or escape the Transaction Descendants.
I went through [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336669/check-if-an-element-exists-when-parsing-xml) but getting error Error **"Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class"**

```
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(file);

foreach (var trans in xDocument.Descendants("Transaction"))
{
    var val1 = (string)trans.Descendants("Set").Elements("szSerialNmbr").First();

    var val2 = (string)trans.Descendants("Set").Elements("lMediaNmbr").First();

    var val3 = (string)trans.Descendants("Set").Elements("lMediaMember").First(); 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if an element exists when parsing XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336669/check-if-an-element-exists-when-parsing-xml)

Comment: i have tried this but not working. i am getting error  "Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class"

Comment: @Lutch then put it in a non-generic static class, and import that class ;) (name it xmlExtensions or whatever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do a null check by adding a `?`, also if you are not sure if your set will contain the object you are looking for in linq, you can use `firstOrDefault` to allow `null` as a return value.

```
var val1 = (string)trans?.Descendants("Set")?.Elements("szSerialNmbr")?.FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
```

Comment: its being underline, can't figure out :(

Comment: @Lutch turns out you don't need to specify the ternary selector (the `::null` bit). i updated the answer.

Comment: var val1 = (string)trans.Descendants("Set").Elements("szSerialNmbr").FirstOrDefault();  This one works, thanks