# How do I select specific element name by using LINQ?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

How do I select every `<Event>` with `<tweet>` element in it and skip `<facebook-status-update>` from the below xml file and display the values in it using LINQ? Assuming there is a lot of different events in the xml file and I want to only select the `<Event>` with `<tweet>` element and its content

XML file Content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Letter>
    <Body>
        <Event>
            <eventid>ID1</eventid>
            <tweet>
                <text>Tweet update</text>
                <location>
                    <lat>123</lat>
                    <long>456</long>
                </location>
                <datetimestamp>datetimestamp</datetimestamp>
            </tweet>
        </Event>
        <Event>
            <eventid>ID2</eventid>
            <facebook-status-update>
                <text>facebook status update</text>
                <location>
                    <lat>789</lat>
                    <long>101</long>
                </location>
                <datetimestamp>datetimestamp</datetimestamp>
            </facebook-status-update>
        </Event>
        <Event>
            <eventid>ID3</eventid>
            <tweet>
                <text>Tweet update</text>
                <location>
                    <lat>121</lat>
                    <long>314</long>
                </location>
                <datetimestamp>datetimestamp</datetimestamp>
            </tweet>
        </Event>
    </Body>
</Letter>
```

I'm using TwitterEvent class for storing its own event value obtain from the xml file, and I was only able to select the first `<tweet>` element with this C# code:

```
XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\JACK\source\repos\LINQToObject\LINQToObject\Resources\xmlFile.xml");
var someEvents = (from _event in xmldoc.Descendants("Body").Elements("Event")                                 
                              select new TwitterEvent
                              {
                                  EventID = _event.Element("eventid").Value,
                                  TweetText = _event.Descendants("tweet").Elements("text").First().Value,
                                  Latitude = _event.Descendants("location").Elements("lat").First().Value,
                                  Longitude = _event.Descendants("location").Elements("long").First().Value,
                                  DateTimeStamp = _event.Descendants("tweet").Elements("datetimestamp").First().Value
                              });
```

Expected output:

```
ID1 Tweet update 123 456 datetimestamp
ID3 Tweet update 121 314 datetimestamp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this too. Every starting node like tweet or location will return array. So, you need to select from that.

```
        var events = XDocument.Load(@"D:\Github\EF\EF.Console\XMLFile1.xml").Descendants("Event");
        var eventResult = events.Where(x=>x.Element("tweet")!=null)
        .Select(_event => new Event
        {
            EventID = _event.Element("eventid").Value,
            TweetText = _event.Descendants("tweet").Select(x => x.Element("text").Value).FirstOrDefault(),
            DateTimeStamp = _event.Descendants("tweet").Select(x => x.Element("datetimestamp").Value).FirstOrDefault(),
            Lat = _event.Descendants("tweet").Select(x => x.Descendants("location").Select(y => y.Element("lat").Value).FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault(),
            Long = _event.Descendants("tweet").Select(x => x.Descendants("location").Select(y => y.Element("long").Value).FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault()
        });
```

Comment: Thank you Amit! This works for me, I wanted to upvote your answer but unfortunately I didn't have enough reputation. But thank you once again!

Comment: Welcome and Thanks for such a good question. For upvote I think you can try again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that is correct but you can try it.

I make a function to check elements like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336669/check-if-an-element-exists-when-parsing-xml/5336713)

```
public static string TryGetElementValue(XElement parentEl, string elementName, string defaultValue = null)
{
     var foundEl = parentEl.Element(elementName);

     if (foundEl != null)
     {
          return foundEl.Value;
     }

     return defaultValue;
}
```

Then I try to add `where` to check "tweet" element:

```
List<TwitterEvent> someEvents;
someEvents = (from _event in xmldoc.Descendants("Body").Elements("Event")
              where TryGetElementValue(_event, "tweet") != null
              select new TwitterEvent()
              {
                     EventID = _event.Element("eventid").Value,
                     TweetText = _event.Descendants("tweet").Elements("text").First().Value,
                     Latitude = _event.Descendants("location").Elements("lat").First().Value,
                     Longitude = _event.Descendants("location").Elements("long").First().Value,
                     DateTimeStamp = _event.Descendants("tweet").Elements("datetimestamp").First().Value
              }).ToList<TwitterEvent>();
```

Comment: Why bother with a whole method? The where statement could be: `where _event.Element("tweet")!=null`. In the other post they had to do it over and over. Here, the check only happens once.

Comment: @dmedine Yes! you're right! I didn't consider that.